# SciPy stats Gamma PDF - unable to successfully shade area under PDF curve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

I have been trying to shade the area under the Gamma distribution PDF using a polygon patch, but no matter what I do the shaded area does not align with the PDF's curve. The polygon vertices are generated directly from the same gamma pdf function.
What is going on here?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gamma
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

x = np.linspace (0, 100, 200)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(20,10))
ax.set_title('Gamma Distribution - Probability Density Function')

y = gamma.pdf(x, a=9, scale = 0.5) #alpha=9, theta =0.5

ax.plot(y, "r-")
ax.legend(['α =9, λ=2'])

ax.set_ylim(0, 0.5)
ax.set_xlim(0,40)

verts = [*zip(x,y)]
poly = Polygon(verts, facecolor='0.9', edgecolor='0.5')
ax.add_patch(poly)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't give both the `x` and `y` arrays to the `plot` function, it assumes that the `x` values are 0, 1, 2, ... `len(y)-1`.  Those are not the correct `x` values for your PDF plot.

Change

```
ax.plot(y, "r-")
```

to

```
ax.plot(x, y, "r-")
```

so that the correct `x` values are used.

With this change (and after changing the figure size to (10, 5)), I get this plot:

[image: plot]